# Exact meanings of Should and Shall in the C++ standard

Tags: c++, standards

I've been reviewing the C++ standard 03 version. And I'm beginning to get confused with the meanings of the words ***Should*** and ***Shall***.

***Shall*** in the standard seems to indicate a compulsory requirement (will-have), where as Should in the standard seems to indicate an optional requirement (could-have). In English, ***Should*** implies an expectation, have I misunderstood the meaning? shouldn't ***Could*** be used instead?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69576/why-are-software-requirements-always-phrased-with-shall-instead-of-will

Comment: @KennyTM: I believe thats more a discussion for CYA'ing of a about-to-be or deployed system. A structural engineer can't come and say this bridge shall be made with 10 pylons, there has to be a certainty should it not?

Comment: In standardese *shall* is nicer way of saying must. And like you say, *should* expects an implementation to behave in a certain way, unless it is in some way unreasonable.

Comment: @KennyTM: Related, but certainly not a duplicate. In particular, "should" is not even mentioned in that one.

Comment: Hmm. Shoulds in a standards document. That said, most of the 'should' statements appear to be parenthetical remarks or constraints against the programmer (as opposed to the implementation). e.g., we programmers should use #include <unistd.h> but #include "myprog.h".

Comment: It is mentioned in the document linked from the accepted answer http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt

Comment: @Kenny: See http://www.plainlanguage.gov/howto/guidelines/bigdoc/writeMust.cfm. But apparently many federal agencies are rebelling.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thus I said "See" not close as duplicate.

Comment: @KennyTM: OK, I didn't know who was voting to close. Five people voted to use that as a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From ISO TR 10176, *Information technology – Guidelines for the preparation of programming language standards*:

3.7 **Auxiliary verbs used in this text**

3.7.1 **shall**:
An indication of a requirement on programming language standard or processors.

3.7.2 **should**:
An indication of a recommendation to programming language standard or processors.

3.7.3 **may**:
An indication of an optional feature of programming language standard or processors. When this Technical Report provides a recommendation to the programming language standard that supports a specific optional feature, the auxiliary verb “may” is used in the sentence explaining the condition.

This is from the 2002 revision, the current revision is 2003, but I assume it hasn't changed much.  (The current revision appears to be available for 150 euros, a bit steep.  I found the 2002 revision here: http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/wg20/docs/n970-tr10176-2002.pdf.)

Comment: Note that this TR is not referenced by the C++ standard, and there are other verbs besides these three which are the only ones it defines. Right now I'm hung up on a "can."

Comment: You can find further explanations here: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/wiki/Specification-Style-Guidelines#standards-wording-idioms

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 *shall* is used in places where C++03 used *must*, probably because it sounds nicer.

*Should* is sometimes used when you want to prescribe something, but it is outside the control of the language, like

> Implementations should ensure that all unblocked threads eventually make progress. [Note: Standard library functions may silently block on I/O or locks. Factors in the execution environment, including externally-imposed thread priorities, may prevent an implementation from making certain guarantees of forward progress. — end note ]

The language prescribes that the C++ runtime "must" treat threads fairly, but what can you do about a system manager lowering the priority?

Comment: The US government disagrees with you, Bo. (I am not saying I disagree.) See the link in my comment on the question.

Comment: @David: the objection you link to seems to be based on some ideal that "shall" is ambiguous. Since ISO explicitly defines the meaning of "shall" in ISO standards, the objection is irrelevant. I'm also pretty sure that the plain-English preferred "You must file an appeal of that decision within 30 days." is inadequately precise for standardese, since I'm pretty sure the intended meaning is *not* that you must file an appeal, rather that you may file an appeal with in 30 days, and may not file an appeal after 30 days. So I reckon ISO wins and the US gov loses.

Comment: Oh, I agree that "shall" has a very specific meaning when used in requirements and in contracts. The US govt is tilting at a windmill here IMHO.

Comment: @David: I'm shocked, *shocked* to find "officious, obsolete" words that have "encumbered legal style writing for many years" in an ISO document!  :)

Comment: @David: in legal language they may well be right. If it's true that courts have held "shall" to have different meanings from the ISO meaning, in different contexts, then it's a genuine problem in law. I've just never seen the meaning of "shall" seriously quibbled in C++, so I agree in this context it's a windmill. Sometimes it's not immediately clear whether it's a requirement on the program or on the implementation, which would be fixed by plain-English avoidance of passive voice, but you can figure it out eventually and anyway that's a whole other style rule :-)

Comment: The usage in technical documents is bass ackwards. In common English, "shall" is often predictive, and "will" frequently signifies intent. (Think, "free will.") "I shall be released." "I will leave now." "This too shall pass." "I will fly the midnight crew, Where boist'rous joy is but a name."