# Rationale for #define over #def and for #undef over #undefine

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, naming

Does anyone know (or can guess) the rationale for:

- `#define` over `#def`
- `#undef` over `#undefine`

Reason:

- expected: symmetry: `#define` or `#def`, and `#undefine` or `#undef` => easy to remember
- actual: no symmetry: `#define` and `#undef` => not easy to remember

Comment: These are just arbitrary choices made by the original language designer, fitting their personal esthetics. You could just as easily as "why `int` rather than `integer`?"

Comment: why `unsigned` instead of `uns`

Comment: One thing to remember is that in the 1970's memory and disk space were not cheap. So language designers had to compromise between readability and terseness.

Comment: That's why `mv` and `cp` rather than `move` (or `rename`) and `copy`.

Comment: @Barmar, don't forget about `dd` that stays for "copy and convert".

Comment: Successful languages (human as well as computer) are rarely perfectly regular or symmetrical.

Comment: @tstanisl `dd` is the most accurate of the names if you associate it with "Disk Destroyer" :)

Comment: @pmor: Not an answer, but a good datapoint. [Six characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38042724/1566221)

Comment: @rici Thanks. Maybe [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66336788/does-name-of-stdatomic-h-contradict-with-potential-restriction-of-the-mapping).

Comment: @SteveSummit In some human languages a negation may change [grammatical case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_case), which I totally unexpect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not easy to remember

Very easy - just two keywords.

> Does anyone know (or can guess) the rationale for:

I believe there was no rationale behind it (except many laziness `#undefine` 9 char long)  - the best person to ask is Alan Snyder who introduced the preprocessor to C language. But probably he does not have the logical answer to this question.